# Little help in flash template image slider?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

Hi people i am using a flash template for my project sorry i don't know nothing about flash and action script. The link to flash template is this http://www.massivetemplates.com/free-flash-templates/photography/photoshot-site. There are categories of image slider like Object, Animals, I want to create more category than four fixed categories. There is also an xml file in it and actionscript file these two files implement image slider. Please see the code from site i am in trouble please give some direction that how to increase categories for this slider though you can modify existing categories. I have populate the xml file but nothing happen thanks please donot delete the question i need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a quick look in the Fla file it seems the categories are not dynamically set. As you might have noticed you can change their labels. Unfortunatly you'll have to edit the source code to create extra (or remove some) categories.

If you still want to edit it you can start digging around in `sprite 202`. This Sprite contains the four buttons and their animations. The four buttons each have their own reference and their own onRelease handlers (this will trigger when you click). The buttons are named: `sprite 191`, `sprite 194`, `sprite 197`, `sprite 200`. In their script they refer to the xml and some functions in the root, the only difference in their script is the `num = x;` line in the top. What's left for you is to find out where the `_root.playGallery();` is called and find out what happens there. For adding and deleting categories you'll just need to copy / delete and rename the buttons mentioned above.

But I guess you should ask someone with some Actionscript 2.0 knowledge to help you with that.

Good luck!